# Consider a function $f(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3$. Let $s$ be the sum of all real roots of $f(x)$ and $t=|s|$. Then...

Tags: calculus, functions, area, cubics

the real number $s$ lies in the interval

(A)$(-0.75,-0.5)$

(B)$(-0.5,0)$

(C)$(0,1)$

(D)$(-0.25,0)$

and the area of region bounded by $f(x),y=0,x=0$ lies in the interval

(A)$(0.75,3)$

(B)$(0,\frac{21}{64})$

(C)$(\frac{21}{64},\frac{11}{16})$

(D)$(9,10)$

***attempt***

$f'(x)$ has no roots. $x=-0.25$ is a point of inflection. The root lies in $(-1,-0.5)$.

Hence (A) is the correct answer.

For second part, the area is $t+t^2+t^3+t^4$.

Its minimum value is when $f(t)=0$. And since A is correct for first part, $t\in(0.75,0.5)$, the Maximum value is when $t=0.75$ and minimum value is when $t$ is the root of the actual equation. How do I find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $f'(x)$ has no (real) roots, but you've miscalculated the point of inflection. Also, there's no particular purpose (that I can think of) to calculating the point of inflection, in the first place. Instead, one could easily use the Intermediate Value Theorem on $(-0.75,-0.5),$ since $f$ has only one real root (why?).

Also, $(0.75,0.5)$ makes no sense, and neither does "$f(t)=0.$" Rather, we know that $t\in(0.5,0.75),$ so letting $g(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4,$ we have that $$g(0.5)<g(t)<g(0.75).$$ (Can you see why?) Can you take it from here?